# Saving AVAudioRecording at path

Tags: ios

I managed to set up the AVAudiorecorder to make recordings, but I would like to save the recording in the documents directory to listen to it later. I tried this:

```
- (void) audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)avrecorder successfully:(BOOL)flag{

ButtonStopRecording.hidden = YES;

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"audioFile.ext"];  // Where ext is the audio format extension you have recorded your sound
[avrecorder.data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

}
```

but there is an error in

```
avrecorder.data
```

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: By now you must know that if you post a question about an error you should include the complete error in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try accessing the file using

```
avrecorder.url
```

It assumes that you have setup your recorder correctly when you begin `record`

Something like this...

```
NSString *temnpVoiceFile = [NSString pathWithComponents:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject], @"tempVoice.caf", nil]];

// We need to update the file generator
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:temnpVoiceFile];

NSError *error = nil;

// Instantiate an audio recorder.
self.audioRecorder = [[[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:soundFileURL settings:_recordSettings error:&error] autorelease];
NSAssert1(!error, @"error creating audio file = %@", error);

BOOL fileSuccess = [_audioRecorder prepareToRecord];

NSAssert(fileSuccess, @"audio recorder could not be prepared.");
[_audioRecorder record];
```

Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

There is no data property for `AVAudioRecorder`. You just need to set the location to hold the recorded audio when you init the `AVAudioRecorder`. Just set it to the documents directory when you set up your recorder.

Check out the apple docs on [AVAudioRecorder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioRecorder/initWithURL%3asettings%3aerror%3a)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"audioFile.ext"];  // Where ext is the audio format extension you have recorded your sound
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:avrecorder.url];
    [data writeToFile:soundFilePath atomically:YES];
[data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

I think it will be helpful to you.